# DRM with MediaPlayerElement

Tags: uwp, media-player, playready

Migrating some video playing code from Silverlight to UWP.  In the SL app, I used the MediaElement object and its LicenseAcquirer to facilitate the DRM, as follows:

```
mediaElement1.LicenseAcquirer = new ManualLicenseAcquirer(mediaElement1.Name, new Uri(http://www.blah.com/secure/license/playready), UriKind.Absolute));
```

I can't figure out what the equivalent license function is in the MediaPlayerElement.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is an document about [PlayReady DRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/playready-client-sdk#output-protection), please refer it.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT I'm actually trying to find the doppleganger feature in MediaPlayer that emulates the LicenseAcquirer feature in the older MediaElement.  I can't find anything like that in that link.  MediaElement allows me to use one line of code to enable DRM; doesn't MediaPlayer support the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find any quick parallel to migrate to MediaPlayer from MediaElement, and the documentation provided by MS is discombobulated and archaic, and their code examples are enormous, but thankfully someone has already gone through all this pain and was most generous to post a concise clear example of a Windows 10 UWP player.  You can check it out here:

https://www.eyecatch.no/blog/using-playready-and-smooth-streaming-in-a-windows-10-uwp-app/

and his sample code:

https://github.com/azzlack/playready-windows10-sample

A sincere thank you azzlack